# Creating setup of project made in monodevelop in ubuntu

Tags: monodevelop

I have made a demo project in monodevelop in Ubuntu 12.10 that is using MySQL as backend, i want to know how can i create a setup for this project. So that this setup can be run and installed on any linux system and user can use this project. Please its urgent so give me quick response.

Regards 
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Setups don't work the same in Ubuntu as they do in Windows.

In Windows, the "installer" was a `.msi` file that contained needed programs as well as a setup executable that is run.

In Ubuntu, we use packages. The package file format used in Ubuntu the `.deb` file.

Take a peek at [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html) to see how to create a `.deb` package to distribute to other Ubuntu users.

Comment: Your link is broken. Here's an archive link to the same page: https://web.archive.org/web/20140202204939/http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html